# Word for a topic that encourages bias

Tags: single-word-requests

Some topics are not controversial so it is easy to be neutral and rational when discussing them. Other topics are more controversial (e.g., abortion) so they make it difficult to remain objective. Regarding the second group, I want to say (with the word "topics" as subject):

> Some topics [] biased analysis.

What to put in the brackets?
Encourage?
Promote?
Facilitate?
Are vulnerable to?
Are prone to?

Comment: Any of the suggested words could work.The exact word choice is dependent on exactly what you want to say.

Comment: *Invite* or *attract* or *ensure* might work.

Comment: thank you Mike Graham, good choices.

Comment: Just say "open to," that should be easy on the reader.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming bias would be a bad trait for an analysis, consider ***tempt***:

> **1** Entice or attempt to entice (someone) to do or acquire something that they find attractive but know to be wrong or not beneficial.
>   <sub>[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/tempt)</sub>

In your sentence:

> Some topics ***tempt*** biased analysis.

Answer (score 0):

You can say that

> Polarizing topics *predispose* biased analysis.

From Macmillan:

> [**predispose**](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/predispose), *v.tr.*: to make someone likely to think, feel,
>   or behave in a particular way